# Symfony 3.4 - Rendering Custom Views on Every Page Load

Tags: php, symfony, events, twig, symfony-3.4

I have a large application using SF 3.4 and I need to find a better way to do custom rendering based on user on each page load. 
Right now we have listeners for a side menu, a footer, side menu favorites, an application menu, and whether or not you are timed out. These listeners fire a theme event via the render function that adds information pertaining to the users access/favorites/if they are timed out. This cannot be done with roles in twig because we have things like menu favorites that change all the time. 
 
We override the Controller render method to dispatch that theme event and array_merge what we get back with the render function's parameter array like this:

```
  protected function render($view, array $parameters = array(), Response $response = null)
  {
        $themeEvent = new ExampleThemeEvent($this->getUser(), $this->getMyMenuApplication());

        $result = $this->getDispatcher()->dispatch(ExampleThemeEvent::NAME, $themeEvent);

        $parameters = array_merge($result->getModel(),$parameters);

      return parent::render($view, $parameters, $response);
  }
```

Because of this most of our Controllers extend ExampleThemeController instead of just Controller so every page we want to have these features does.

This works fine, but the render method has been marked final as of SF 3.4 and shouldn't be overridden. What would be the best way to approach this without overriding the render method? Is there another place I can dispatch our theme event?
We have tried onKernelController subscribers/listeners to no avail because we need to add the extra view parameters to the container which cannot be done at that point.

 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For such user-specific changes that go beyond passing globals to twig, I'd check out [embedding controllers](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/embedding_controllers.html). You can render a part of your response with a different controller, responsible only for the favourites for example.